# Gradle add native library dir to java.library.path (not for test but for run)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

Maybe someone here can help me.
I have a Java Project in which I use Gradle and process the whole thing in IntelliJ. (Specs down below)

In my project I use JNI and write my own C++ library (.so file) which I put in a directory in my project e.g. `./native/build/lib/main/debug/libnative.so`.

Now, when running my program normally in IntelliJ, I want the VM to add the path of my `.so`-library to the `java.library.path` and use it accordingly.
At the moment I have to do this for each main class individually by going to `Edit Configurations` and under `Modify Options > Add VM Options` add `-Djava.library.path=...../native/build/lib/main/debug`. But somehow it must be possible to set this globally for all classes in gradle, or not ?

I know you can add in `gradle.build` the java.library.path for tests like follows

```
test {
    systemProperty 'java.library.path','path/to/directory'
}
```

but I don't need this for the tests but for the normal run/start of a main function in a class when clicking the green Arrow in IntelliJ. I already tried to add it in all task like follows

```
compileJava {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
processResources {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
classes {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
jar {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
startScripts {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
installDist {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
build {
    "-Djava.library.path=${System.getProperty('java.library.path')}:${project(':native').buildDir}/lib/main/debug"
}
```

but without success. Note that only in `test` 'systemProperty' can be used. Since in other tasks a 'No Signature Method exception' is thrown .When I try to start the program I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no native in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]`.

I use here simply the following class:

```
public class A {
    public static native void print0();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print0();
    }
}
```

and yes, it works when i individually set `-Djava.library.path...` in `Run Configuration`

Environment:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.3.2
- AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11+9 hs
- Gradle 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply changed my approach and am now loading my native libraries at Runtime in the class which defines the native functions using

```
static {
   System.load('absolute Path to .so file')
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For `run` task:

```
application {
    mainClass.set("x.y.ApplicationKt")

    applicationDefaultJvmArgs += listOf(
        "-Djava.library.path=${projectDir}/libs/your_native_library_folder/"
    )
}
```

For my Kotlin project to have tests working:

```
tasks.withType<Test>().all {
    systemProperty(
        "java.library.path",
        "someAbsolutePath:anotherPath" //Replace : with ; for windows
    )
}
```

For typical Gradle projects:

```
test{
    systemProperty(
        "java.library.path",
        "someAbsolutePath:anotherPath" //Replace : with ; for windows
    )
}
```