# Why do I recieve error 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library' when the file can be found?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl, imgui

Why am I receiving this error even though the file is clearly there and it could be read?

[image: The Error]

My project is using lwjgl and imgui-java. I have added -Dimgui.library.path="libs" (where the .dylib in question is stored) to my VM options and the application should open, displaying the demo IMGUI.

I have also posted my build.gradle file below:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.tpsgames'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.3.1"
project.ext.jomlVersion = "1.10.4"
project.ext.imguiVersion = '1.86.4'
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"

switch (OperatingSystem.current()) {
    case OperatingSystem.MAC_OS:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = System.getProperty("os.arch").startsWith("aarch64") ? "natives-macos-arm64" : "natives-macos"
        break
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:$lwjglVersion")
    implementation "io.github.spair:imgui-java-app:1.86.4"
    implementation platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:$lwjglVersion")
    implementation fileTree('libs') {include '*.jar'}
    ['', '-opengl', '-glfw'].each {
        implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl$it:$lwjglVersion"
        implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl$it::natives-macos"
    }
    implementation "io.github.spair:imgui-java-binding:1.86.4"
    implementation "io.github.spair:imgui-java-lwjgl3:1.86.4"
    implementation "io.github.spair:imgui-java-natives-macos:1.86.4"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-nfd"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-nfd::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb::$lwjglNatives"
    implementation "org.joml:joml:1.10.4"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065002/12844632 or add `systemProperty "java.library.path", "/path/to/native/lib` to your build.gradle.

Comment: Sorry, neither worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your computer *very likely* has a CPU with the ARM architecture, such as the M1 chip, instead of the x86 architecture.

Therefore, the JVM process cannot load the imgui-java64.dylib shared library because imgui-java currently only ships x86 CPU architecture shared libraries, not ARM ones.

See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/SpaiR/imgui-java/issues/123
and this (currently open) GitHub Pull Request: https://github.com/SpaiR/imgui-java/pull/112 to add ARM CPU support for imgui-java.

Your only solution is to probably incorporate the work currently having been done in that GitHub Pull Request and compile imgui-java locally yourself for your ARM CPU or wait until the PR is merged and a release of imgui-java ships with macOS ARM shared libraries.